# How to use the tooltipTemplate on Chart.JS 2.0

Tags: javascript, tooltip, chart.js

I am trying to use the doughnut chart with multiple datasets and also use the tooltipTemplate feature to customize the text inside the tooltips but nothing works. This worked in the previous Chart js version but that doesn't support multiple datasets. Can anyone help? Below is my code:

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
        tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=value%><%} else {%> No data <%}%>",
    },
}
```

Comment: You have to use `callbacks.label`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158477/where-put-multitooltiptemplate-in-chat-js-v2-x for an example.

Answer (score 34):

As potatopeelings has mentioned in the comments, you have to set a callback for the tooltip.

Here is an example:

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || 'Other';
        var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
        return datasetLabel + ': ' + label;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

live demo

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Men", "Women", "Unknown"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Sweden',
            data: [60, 40, 20],
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(158, 216, 202, 0.75)', 'rgba(255, 150, 162, 0.75)', 'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.75)']
        }, {
            label: 'Netherlands',
            data: [40, 70, 10],
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(158, 216, 202, 0.5)', 'rgba(255, 150, 162, 0.5)', 'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.5)']
        }, {
            data: [33, 33, 34],
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(158, 216, 202, 0.25)', 'rgba(255, 150, 162, 0.25)', 'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.25)']
        }]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || 'Other';
                    var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                    return datasetLabel + ': ' + label;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 14):

The Chart.js 1.x tooltipsTemplate is equivalent to `options.tooltips.callbacks.title` in Chart.js 2.x:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "Men",
      "Women",
      "Unknown"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Sweden',
      data: [60, 40, 20],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(158, 216, 202, 0.75)',
        'rgba(255, 150, 162, 0.75)',
        'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.75)'
      ]
    }, {
      label: 'Netherlands',
      data: [40, 70, 10],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(158, 216, 202, 0.5)',
        'rgba(255, 150, 162, 0.5)',
        'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.5)'
      ]
    }, {
      data: [33, 33, 34],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(158, 216, 202, 0.25)',
        'rgba(255, 150, 162, 0.25)',
        'rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.25)'
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                return 'This value ' + tooltipItem.yLabel;
        },
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
           return 'The tooltip title ' + tooltipItem[0].xLabel;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `options` for tooltip `mode` to `label` for showing multiple tooltip

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
        mode : 'label'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the label you can simply try this

```
options = 
  {                       
    tooltips :{          
      titleFontSize : 0,
      titleMarginBottom:-0.5
    }
  }
```

tooltip reference https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html