# ChartJS v2 custom tooltip for rLabel

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a ChartJS (v2) bubble chart with three dimensions: x, y, and r (radius of the bubble).

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158477/where-put-multitooltiptemplate-in-chat-js-v2-x), I have this code for customizing the tooltip:

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
      var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
      return datasetLabel + ' : ' + tooltipItem.rLabel + '% has price of ' + tooltipItem.yLabel + ' USD';
    }
  }
}
```

It almost works except that `tooltipItem.rLabel` is displayed as `undefined`. If I input `tooltipItem.xLabel` the tooltip displays correctly with the value of `x`. However, I want to display the value of `r`.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **rLabel** value is not a property of **tooltipItem** that's why it gives undefined. I access that value from the **data** object.

```
  tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        rLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index].r;
                        var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                        return datasetLabel + ' : ' + rLabel + '% har pris på ca. ' + tooltipItem.yLabel + ' kr.';
                    }
                }
            }
```

Below is the working code for the same.

```
var data = {
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'First Dataset',
                data: [
                    {
                        x: 20,
                        y: 30,
                        r: 15
                    },
                    {
                        x: 40,
                        y: 10,
                        r: 10
                    }
                ],
                backgroundColor:"#FF6384",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "#FF6384",
            }
        ]
    };
    var myBubbleChart = new Chart(ctx,{
        type: 'bubble',
        data: data,
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        rLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index].r;
                        var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                        return datasetLabel + ' : ' + rLabel + '% har pris på ca. ' + tooltipItem.yLabel + ' kr.';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. One small thing rLabel is displayed with 17 decimals. I there a way to limit the number of decimals?

Comment: @Wessi you can `Math.round(num)`  for round the value of num or there is another post on stackoverflow to round number up to two places.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 1):

After trying for hours, turns out in my case, I needed to add `var` before `rLabel`...

Otherwise, it just kept alerting me there was a js error in developer console...

In my case :

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      var rLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index].r;
      var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
      return datasetLabel + ' : ' + rLabel + '% har pris på ca. ' + tooltipItem.yLabel + ' kr.';
    }
  }
}
```

Still, thanks very very much for the answer from Sanjay Dutt !

Answer (score 0):

```
this may help in solving the build error.

 label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        let radiusArr:any;
        radiusArr = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
        let rLabel = radiusArr.r;
        let datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
        return rLabel + ' xxx are ' + datasetLabel;
    },
```